# Efficiently store multiple integral numbers in a single variable (and retrieve them)

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let's assume that we have up to 3 IDs (we don't know the number of IDs before, can be 0 to 3), each of them can consist of up to 4 digits, leading to numbers from 1 to 9999. Since these IDs are small enough, we want to store them in a single variable and not an array (for whatever reasons), such as a double. Here is an example of what I mean:

We have 3 IDs: ID_1 = 1234, ID_2 = 0987, and ID_3 = 6543. We pair these and obtain the following as a result: 654309871234
As we can see, the numbers are still there and could be obtained from it.

Something like this, we could accomplish by using the following code:

```
int maxDigits = 4;
double result = 1; // needed at the start, so that log10 works
int id[3] = {1234, 0987, 6543};

for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
  int pos = log10(result) / maxDigits;
  result += pow(10, pos * maxDigits + 1) * id;  
}
```

This would have a slightly different outcome: `result = 6543098712341`, but we can still retrieve the information.

However, I don't think that this is an efficient way of handling this. Maybe one should rather operate in binaries and not decimals? What would be a better (more efficient) approach?

(The above-mentioned ID range mustn't be the same for other possible solutions.)

Comment: The `3 IDs: ID_1 = 1234, ID_2 = 0987, and ID_3 = 6543` should fit in an unsigned integer with some bitshifts. Did you try that? (`double` is best left out for efficiency)

Comment: This is what [bitfields in structs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) are for.

Comment: Also, I don't find _for whatever reasons_ to be a compelling reason not to write a class or  a struct and let the compiler optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDs can go up to 9999, which requires 14 bits max. 3 integers of 14 bits each would require 42 bits max. You can easily store that in a 64-bit `unsigned long` or `uint64_t` with some manual bit-shifting, eg:

```cpp
uint16_t get_id(uint64_t ids, uint8_t which)
{
    return (ids >> (14 * (which & 3))) & 0x3FFF;
}

void set_id(uint64_t &ids, uint8_t which, uint16_t id)
{
    uint64_t shift = 14 * (which & 3);
    ids = (ids & ~((0x3FFF << shift))) | ((id & 0x3FFF) << shift);
}

uint64_t ids = 0;
set_id(ids, 0, 1234);
set_id(ids, 1, 0987);
set_id(ids, 2, 6543);
...
id1 = get_id(ids, 0);
id2 = get_id(ids, 1);
id3 = get_id(ids, 2);
```

Or, you can use [bitfields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) to let the compiler handle the bit-shifting for you, eg:

```cpp
struct s_ids
{
    uint64_t id1: 14;
    uint64_t id2: 14;
    uint64_t id3: 14;
};

s_ids ids;
ids.id1 = 1234;
ids.id2 = 0987;
ids.id3 = 6543;
...
id1 = ids.id1;
id2 = ids.id2;
id3 = ids.id3;
```

Or, you could just use a normal `struct` of normal 16-bit integers and don't do any fancy bit-twiddling at all:

```cpp
struct s_ids
{
    uint16_t id1;
    uint16_t id2;
    uint16_t id3;
};

s_ids ids;
ids.id1 = 1234;
ids.id2 = 0987;
ids.id3 = 6543;
...
id1 = ids.id1;
id2 = ids.id2;
id3 = ids.id3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store these values in an easy way in a double: If you remove the sign and the exponent bits from a double, you're left with 52 bits to store your value. However lg(52) = 15.65... (lg denoting the logarithm with a basis of 2 here). This means you'd be left with less than 4 decimal digits per ID which is insufficient to store the kind of info you want to store.

Instead use a unsigned integer type that's guaranteed to contain enough bits. 64 bit happens to be sufficient to store 4 ids containing 16 bits each (2^16 = 65536) and you can retrieve the ids efficiently using bit operations:

```
/**
 * \param previous the combined ids storing new value
 * \param index an index between 0 and 3 (inclusive) for the id to store
 * \param value the id to store
 * \return the new combined value after replacing the id at index with value
 */
uint64_t storeId(uint64_t previous, uint64_t index, uint64_t value)
{
    return (previous ^ (0xffff << (index * 16))) | (value << (index * 16)); 
}

/**
 * \return the id stored in value at index index
 */
uint64_t getId(uint64_t value, uint64_t index)
{
    return (value >> (index * 16)) & 0xffff;
}
```